# Can't update users email address or password using Thinktecture IdMgr + MembershipReboot.

Tags: thinktecture, membershipreboot

When I edit a user in Thinktecture IdManager I can change their name, and age and other "custom" properties but when I try to change their email address or password my custom Membership Reboot repository update method is called once to save the change and then again to revert the change.

The controller is called twice by AutoFac container middleware for some reason.

There is only 1 HTTP post coming from the IdMgr application so it's not a client side issue.

The first stack trace is...

```
Gaist.Authentication.dll!Gaist.Authentication.MR.MembershipRebootRepository.Update(Gaist.Authentication.Mongo.Models.CustomUser item) Line 71    C#
[External Code]    
IdentityManager.MembershipReboot.dll!IdentityManager.MembershipReboot.MembershipRebootIdentityManagerService<Gaist.Authentication.Mongo.Models.CustomUser,Gaist.Authentication.Mongo.Models.CustomGroup>.SetPassword(Gaist.Authentication.Mongo.Models.CustomUser account, string password) Line 235    C#
IdentityManager.dll!IdentityManager.ExpressionPropertyMetadata<Gaist.Authentication.Mongo.Models.CustomUser,string>.Set(object instance, string value) Line 87    C#
IdentityManager.dll!IdentityManager.PropertyMetadataExtensions.TrySet(IdentityManager.PropertyMetadata property, object instance, string value, out IdentityManager.IdentityManagerResult result) Line 137    C#
IdentityManager.dll!IdentityManager.PropertyMetadataExtensions.TrySet(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<IdentityManager.PropertyMetadata> properties, object instance, string type, string value, out IdentityManager.IdentityManagerResult result) Line 123    C#
IdentityManager.MembershipReboot.dll!IdentityManager.MembershipReboot.MembershipRebootIdentityManagerService<Gaist.Authentication.Mongo.Models.CustomUser,Gaist.Authentication.Mongo.Models.CustomGroup>.SetUserProperty(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<IdentityManager.PropertyMetadata> propsMeta, Gaist.Authentication.Mongo.Models.CustomUser user, string type, string value) Line 590    C#
IdentityManager.MembershipReboot.dll!IdentityManager.MembershipReboot.MembershipRebootIdentityManagerService<Gaist.Authentication.Mongo.Models.CustomUser,Gaist.Authentication.Mongo.Models.CustomGroup>.SetUserPropertyAsync(string subject, string type, string value) Line 503    C#
IdentityManager.dll!IdentityManager.Api.Models.Controllers.UserController.SetPropertyAsync(string subject, string type) Line 205    C#
[External Code]    
IdentityManager.dll!IdentityManager.Configuration.Hosting.KatanaDependencyResolver.SendAsync(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) Line 35    C#
[External Code]    
IdentityManager.dll!IdentityManager.Configuration.Hosting.AutofacContainerMiddleware.Invoke(System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string,object> env) Line 51    C#
[External Code]    
IdentityManager.dll!Owin.IdentityManagerAppBuilderExtensions.UseIdentityManager(Microsoft.Owin.IOwinContext ctx, System.Func<System.Threading.Tasks.Task> next) Line 55    C#
[Resuming Async Method]    
[External Code]
```

The second stack trace is ...

```
Gaist.Authentication.dll!Gaist.Authentication.MR.MembershipRebootRepository.Update(Gaist.Authentication.Mongo.Models.CustomUser item) Line 71   C#
[External Code] 
IdentityManager.MembershipReboot.dll!IdentityManager.MembershipReboot.MembershipRebootIdentityManagerService<Gaist.Authentication.Mongo.Models.CustomUser,Gaist.Authentication.Mongo.Models.CustomGroup>.SetUserPropertyAsync(string subject, string type, string value) Line 511   C#
IdentityManager.dll!IdentityManager.Api.Models.Controllers.UserController.SetPropertyAsync(string subject, string type) Line 205    C#
[External Code] 
IdentityManager.dll!IdentityManager.Configuration.Hosting.KatanaDependencyResolver.SendAsync(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) Line 35  C#
[External Code] 
IdentityManager.dll!IdentityManager.Configuration.Hosting.AutofacContainerMiddleware.Invoke(System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string,object> env) Line 51  C#
[External Code] 
IdentityManager.dll!Owin.IdentityManagerAppBuilderExtensions.UseIdentityManager(Microsoft.Owin.IOwinContext ctx, System.Func<System.Threading.Tasks.Task> next) Line 55 C#
[Resuming Async Method] 
[External Code]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was happening because the MembershipRebootIdentityManagerService implementation that comes out of the box was assuming that the repository would be based on Entity Framework and that calling save twice would be working on the same instance of an EF context and therfore the same entity.

My repo implementation didn't work that way so it was loading an unsaved entity and then overwriting the settings.

I had to frig my repository to hold onto the entity that's being edited for the lifetime of the repo.